# What is Dart's equivalent to Kotlin's let?

Tags: kotlin, dart, flutter

Recently I've been delving into Flutter's ecosystem and Dart has proven itself a neat and simple language.

Currently, I am looking for a best practice to **run methods if an optional variable is not null.**

In other words, I am looking for something in Dart that is like Kotlin's **let operator** :

```
variable?.let {
    doStuff();
    doABitMoreStuff();
    logStuff();
}
```

Anyone got any ideas or best practices around this?

I've looked into Dart's documentation and have found nothing that would fit my requirements.

King regards,

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish. I don't think there is a direct equivalent. I don't know Kotlin and the docs don't tell much. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html

Comment: Probably `if(variable != null)`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am trying to avoid the null check. That seems a bit java-like and given that dart is a recent language (like swift and kotlin) I was assuming it would have a similar 'let' key.

Comment: Dart has the `?.` operator too. Just no that sort of block yet

Comment: "I am trying to avoid the null check". But you are doing a null check, you just write it as `?` instead of `== null`. Note that `if (variable == null) { /* ... */ }` is much easier to read than `variable?.let { ... }` while it is essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 28):

With the new Dart extension functions, we can define:

```
extension ObjectExt<T> on T {
  R let<R>(R Function(T that) op) => op(this);
}
```

This will allow to write `x.let(f)` instead of `f(x)`.

Comment: This is slightly overcomplicated. The following works just fine: `R let<R>(R Function(T) x) => x(this);`

Comment: @JoshuaHyatt in older Dart versions the “as” cast was required.

Comment: can some1 update for current version ?

Comment: A caveat to be aware of with this, that took me some hours to figure out, is that dynamics need to be cast for the let function to "exist":   
Won't work: `dynamic foo=3; foo.let((ouch){});`,   
Will work: `dynamic foo=3; (foo as int).let((ouch){});`

Answer (score 12):

Dart's equivalent would be a null-aware cascade operator:
The Dart approach would be a to use a *null-aware cascade*:

```dart
SomeType? variable = ...

variable
   ?..doStuff()
    ..doABitMoreStuff()
    ..logStuff();
```

The null-aware cascade works like the normal cascade, except that if the receiver value is `null`, it does nothing.

---

You could make your own using a static function though:

```
typedef T LetCallback<T>(T value);

T let<T>(T value, LetCallback<T> cb) {
  if (value != null) {
    return cb(value);
  }
}
```

Then used like that:

```
let<MyClass>(foo, (it) {

})
```

Comment: Thanks. Although this is the solution I am already implementing, it is not necessarily what I was looking for.
I would live to have both a closure and the null checking inside the same construct, much like kotlin's let.

Comment: Dart doesn't have that. It probably won't until Dart has extensions methods. You could create your own using a static function. Although the syntax will be slightly different

Comment: @RicardoVieira I added a small example

Answer (score 5):

We can do it with Dart 2.6 or later.

```dart
extension ScopeFunctionsForObject<T extends Object> on T {
  ReturnType let<ReturnType>(ReturnType operation_for(T self)) {
    return operation_for(this);
  }
}
```

usage: https://github.com/YusukeIwaki/dart-kotlin_flavor#let

Comment: It doesn't work on Flutter. It compiles but then in runtime: `exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'let'.
`

Comment: That's because your map variable has static type `dynamic`. Extension methods only work on non-`dynamic`-typed values. That's another reason to avoid `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `x?.let{ }` and `if (x != null) { }` in Kotlin is that the former promotes `x` to be non-nullable. Since Kotlin has non-nullable types, it prevents you from needing to write `x!!` to assert the non-nullability inside the block.

Dart doesn't have non-nullable types (yet), so that distinction isn't important in Dart.
Just use `if (x != null) { ... }`.
If Dart gets non-nullable types, you can be assured that the `null` check in the condition will also promote `x` to non-nullable inside the block (if `x` is a local variable, is not mutated inside the block, other restrictions may apply).
(EDIT: Dart now has nullable types, and `x != null` promotes `x` to non-`null`.)

From your other comments, it sounds like you might be wanting the Kotlin behavior  of `x?.run { ... }` instead, which binds `this` to `x` inside the lambda block. There is no corresponding feature in Dart. You cannot override `this`, it's always bound to the the object that the current method was called on, even inside nested closures which captures the value of `this` just as they capture other variables.

Answer (score 1):

Using this extension:

```
extension Ext on Object? {
    void ifNotNull(Function() action) {
        if(this != null){
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

You can achieve something similar:

```
object.ifNotNull(() => {
    // safe code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though Dart doesn't have the `let` like behavior as of Kotlin but we can certainly emulate it with concise and readable code. Maybe something like this:

```
void main() {
  String str = null;

  str?.isEmpty ?? Function.apply(() {
    print("Hey there you cheeky null valued variable");
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i implemented let function with extension function like this:

```
extension KotlinLet on Object?{
  void let(Function callback ){
    if (this != null) {
      callback();
    }
  }
 Object? also(){
    if (this != null) {
     return this;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this package **kotlin_flavor**: https://pub.dev/packages/kotlin_flavor/install

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same behaviour with an extension. Here is one extension that behaves like Kotlin's *let* and takes one function to be performed on the non-null object.

```
extension NotNull<T extends Object> on T {
  void ifNotNull(Function(T) action) {
    action(this);
  }
}
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
final int? value = 42;
value?.ifNotNull((v) => print(v));   // Prints "42"
```

or

```
final int? value;
value?.ifNotNull((v) => print(v));   // Prints nothing
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess a closure does what you want

```
class Foo {
  var x = 42;
  void bar() {
    () {
      print(x);
      doStuff();
      doABitMoreStuff();
      logStuff();
    }();
  }
}
```

Comment: The closure is nice but I was looking for something like a nullcheck combined with a closure, pretty much like kotlin's let.

Comment: I got that when I saw the other comments but Remi was faster. It's always a good idea to state what problem or use case you want to solve instead mentioning features from other languages, frameworks, ...

Answer (score -2):

There is no direct equivalent, because there is no need for it in Dart. Dart is a lot more like Java and you often end up with similar solutions.

There is almost no syntactic sugar in Dart. It's supposed to be easy to learn.

Also, Dart does not enforce strict null checks, all variables are nullable, and the language is single-threaded. That's why there is no need for `let`. Use `if` instead:

```
if(variable != null) {
  doStuff();
  doABitMoreStuff();
  logStuff();
}
```

Comment: What you propose does not answer the question. It has to be:  

```dart
if(variable != null) {
  variable..doStuff()..doABitMoreStuff()..logStuff();
}
```  

I think `let` is more elegant in doing this than what we have in dart today. To implement it, we need what is called receivers (method pointers) in Dart.  

Having method pointers, will also allow Koltin style DSLs in Dart.

Comment: To get that behavior in Kotlin, I believe (after cursory reading) that you should use `run` instead of `let`. The code here matches the `let` method of Kotlin in that it binds the `variable` object to the lambda parameter, not the default receiver.

Comment: @lrn exactly, `let` would give you access to the `variable` as `it`, perhaps OP is intending to use it as `this`?