# Null guard / unwrapping in a single line in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, null, nullable, dart-null-safety

Single line in Kotlin

```
val prop = a?.prop ?: return
```

Single line in Swift

```
guard let prop = a?.prop else { return }
```

Can this two line be single in dart ?

```
var prop = a?.prop
if (prop != null) { return }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Dart's equivalent to Kotlin's let?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148319/what-is-darts-equivalent-to-kotlins-let)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is not what I am looking for. The title of the question is to unwrap nullable in a single line. What you are proposing is a to run some functions using an extension