# How can an `extension` reference the type of `this` in dart?

Tags: dart, types, this, self-reference

Let's say I have some datatypes, and I want a function `gimmeThis()` that simply returns `this`. Currently, the code in `main()` does not compile, because the result of `gimmeThis()` is `MyClass`. How can I change the extension class to return a more specific type when `gimmeThis()` is called?

```dart
class MyClass {}
class MySubclass1 extends MyClass {}
class MySubclass2 extends MyClass {}

extension MyClassOperations on MyClass {
  // how to replace `MyClass` with the actual type of `this`?
  MyClass gimmeThis() => this;
}

void main() {
  MySubclass1 sub1 = MySubclass1().gimmeThis();
  MySubclass2 sub2 = MySubclass2().gimmeThis();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just did a little more digging, and I actually found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58762538/20027466) that gives insight to the answer I was looking for!

```dart
extension MyClassOperations<MyClassT extends MyClass> on MyClassT {
  MyClassT gimmeThis() => this;
}
```

What?! Extending a generic type?!! Dart is such a cool language, I keep learning about new ways to use it that just makes programming in it so much fun!